# EPPlus date format but Excel shows error

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

```
 ws.Column(5).Style.Numberformat.Format = "m/d/yyyy";
```

I am setting column's cell format as date, in spite of that Excel shows error besides every cell. Why?

Comment: Waht is the error exactly? `m` for minutes, use `M` which is for months by the way.

Comment: What is the Error message that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I do this to write date into excel

```
dateCell.Formula = String.Format(
    "=DATE({0},{1},{2})",
    clientFileDate.Year,
    clientFileDate.Month,
    clientFileDate.Day
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use DateTime.FromOADate()

var dateToBeFormat = ws.Column(5).Value.Tostring()
var finalDate = DateTime.FromOADate(dateToBeFormat);